# How can I build ADB with Ndk for Android Apps

Tags: android, android-ndk, adb

I want to build Android ADB with NDK such that the .so that obtained can be used in my project
the .mk file is as follow:

```
# Copyright 2005 The Android Open Source Project
#
# Android.mk for adb
#

LOCAL_PATH:= $(call my-dir)
#adbd device daemon
# =========================================================

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_SRC_FILES := \
adb.c \
fdevent.c \
transport.c \
transport_local.c \
transport_usb.c \
adb_auth_client.c \
sockets.c \
services.c \
file_sync_service.c \
jdwp_service.c \
framebuffer_service.c \
remount_service.c \
usb_linux_client.c

LOCAL_CFLAGS := \
-O2 \
-g \
-DADB_HOST=0 \
-D_XOPEN_SOURCE \
-D_GNU_SOURCE \
-Wall -Wno-unused-parameter -Werror -Wno-deprecated-declarations \

ifneq (,$(filter userdebug eng,$(TARGET_BUILD_VARIANT)))
LOCAL_CFLAGS += -DALLOW_ADBD_ROOT=1
endif

LOCAL_MODULE := adbd

LOCAL_FORCE_STATIC_EXECUTABLE := true
LOCAL_MODULE_PATH := $(TARGET_ROOT_OUT_SBIN)
LOCAL_UNSTRIPPED_PATH := $(TARGET_ROOT_OUT_SBIN_UNSTRIPPED)

LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES := liblog libcutils libc libmincrypt libselinux
LOCAL_ADDITIONAL_DEPENDENCIES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/Android.mk
include $(BUILD_EXECUTABLE)
```

but i cannot build it by android-ndk-r9c

is this way possible? 
what should i do ?

could anyone help me ?

the errors during building are :

```
jni/adb.c:31:0:
jni/sysdeps.h: In function 'adb_shutdown':
jni/sysdeps.h:363:5: error: implicit declaration of function 'shutdown' [-Werror=implicit-            function-declaration]
jni/sysdeps.h:363:25: error: 'SHUT_RDWR' undeclared (first use in this function)
jni/sysdeps.h:363:25: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
jni/sysdeps.h: At top level:
jni/sysdeps.h:418:81: error: unknown type name 'socklen_t'
jni/sysdeps.h: In function 'adb_socket_setbufsize':
jni/sysdeps.h:453:5: error: implicit declaration of function 'setsockopt' [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
jni/sysdeps.h: In function 'unix_socketpair':
jni/sysdeps.h:465:5: error: implicit declaration of function 'socketpair' [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
jni/sysdeps.h: In function 'adb_socketpair':
jni/sysdeps.h:472:36: error: 'SOCK_STREAM' undeclared (first use in this function)
In file included from jni/private/android_filesystem_config.h:33:0,
             from jni/adb.c:39:
jni/private/android_filesystem_capability.h: At top level:
jni/private/android_filesystem_capability.h:37:16: error: redefinition of 'struct __user_cap_header_struct'
D:/cygwin/android-ndk-r9c/platforms/android-5/arch-arm/usr/include/linux/capability.h:20:16: note: originally defined here
D:/NDK/android-ndk-r10c/samples/hello-jni/jni/private/android_filesystem_capability.h:40:11: error: conflicting types for 'cap_user_header_t'
D:/cygwin/android-ndk-r9c/platforms/android-5/arch-arm/usr/include/linux/capability.h:23:11: note: previous declaration of 'cap_user_header_t' was here
D:/NDK/android-ndk-r10c/samples/hello-jni/jni/private/android_filesystem_capability.h:42:16: error: redefinition of 'struct __user_cap_data_struct'
D:/cygwin/android-ndk-r9c/platforms/android-5/arch-arm/usr/include/linux/capability.h:25:16: note: originally defined here
D:/NDK/android-ndk-r10c/samples/hello-jni/jni/private/android_filesystem_capability.h:46:11: error: conflicting types for 'cap_user_data_t'
D:/cygwin/android-ndk-r9c/platforms/android-5/arch-arm/usr/include/linux/capability.h:29:11: note: previous declaration of 'cap_user_data_t' was here
D:/NDK/android-ndk-r10c/samples/hello-jni/jni/private/android_filesystem_capability.h:70:0: error: "_LINUX_CAPABILITY_VERSION" redefined [-Werror]
D:/cygwin/android-ndk-r9c/platforms/android-5/arch-arm/usr/include/linux/capability.h:18:0: note: this is the location of the previous definition
D:/NDK/android-ndk-r10c/samples/hello-jni/jni/adb.c:40:28: fatal error: sys/capability.h: No such file or directory
cc1.exe: all warnings being treated as errors
```

i have tryed build it in by ndk in linux 
after adding coressphonding lib to the floder some erorrs have been solved 
however the redifinition is still there
i comment out the redifinition struct but new problems comes:

```
linux/capability.h:35:10: error:expected '=', ',' , 'j','asm' or'__attribute__' before '*' token } __user * cap_user_header_t
```

By the way, what I realy want is to run the adb command, "adb install" for example, in my apk.Do I need move the entire adbd program to my project? Is there any way to achieve this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible, adbd depends on system libraries that are not exposed by the NDK, some of them have changed between platform releases. Besides, it needs to run with appropriate privileges to work correctly, something you won't be able to do from your application.

Comment: Thanks a lot for ur answer. However I have found that there some apps can input adb commands on cellphone directly. Do you have any idea how can they do this ?  Thanks.

Comment: By the way, what I realy want is to run the adb command, "adb install" for example, in my apk.Do I need move the entire adbd program to my project? Is there any way to achieve this ?

Comment: On some devices, 'adbd' runs in a mode where it also listens on the local TCP port 5037, and the 'adb' command-line client program is installed in /system/bin/. These are typically custom ROMs, not consumer-grade system images though.

In this case, it's possible for an application to invoke the command-line 'adb' through fork()/exec() and run some commands. I don't think you can do that in the general case though.

As for installing an .apk from an application directly, keep in mind this is forbidden by the Play Store Developer Rules (to avoid malware).

Answer (score 0):

you can build adb and fastboot from source for android device.
use this build script, [github](https://github.com/shakalaca/fastboot-adb-android)
in this repo you can see prebuild binary for arm-v7a and arm64